# Use DisplayMemberPath in a ComboBoxItem template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Currently I've hardcoded the property (DisplayName) of the DataContext object that should be shown. But normally you specify this path in the ComboBox itself with the property DisplayMemberPath. How can I use the value specified by DisplayMemberPath as the property to bind against in the content presenter?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border x:Name="ItemBorder"
                            Padding="2,0"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            CornerRadius="3">


                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding DisplayName}"/>


                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger SourceName="ItemBorder" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="ItemBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LightBlueBackgroundBrush}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="ItemBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource LightBlueBackgroundBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

For reference, here is my ComboBox style.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="22"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource MidGreyBorderStroke}"/>
    <Setter Property="Border.CornerRadius" Value="3" />
    <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">

                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding Border.CornerRadius}"
                        Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                        Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">

                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ReadOnlyContentPresenter"
                                          Grid.Column="0"
                                          Margin="5,0"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                          ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" />

                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                                 Grid.Column="0"
                                 Margin="5,0"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                 Visibility="Hidden"
                                 IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" />

                        <Border Grid.Column="1"    
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="1,0,0,0"
                                Margin="0,2" />

                        <ToggleButton Grid.Column="2"
                                      Margin="1,0"
                                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                      Focusable="False"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                      ClickMode="Press"
                                      Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"/>

                        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"
                               AllowsTransparency="True"
                               Placement="Bottom"
                               IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                               Focusable="False"
                               PopupAnimation="Fade"
                               SnapsToDevicePixels="True">

                            <Grid Background="Transparent"
                                  MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                  MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">

                                <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                        BorderThickness="1"
                                        CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding Border.CornerRadius}"
                                        Margin="0,2,0,0">

                                    <ScrollViewer Margin="6,0">
                                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                                                    KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                   </Grid>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".65" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="42"/>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ReadOnlyContentPresenter" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well this is actually an interesting question that has quite an simple answer.

**Short answer**:

```
   <ContentPresenter />
```

**Long answer:**

If you have overridden the `ComboBoxItem` style but you still want to use `DisplayMemberPath` from the `ComboBox` you don't have to put anything into the Styles `Content` binding as the `Parent`(ComboBox) will resolve this for you. Because `DisplayMemberPath` is just a string not the actual property, if you Bind to `DisplayMemberPath` all your items will just show whatever value you put into `DisplayMemberPath`

So all you have to do is remove the `Content` binding from the `ComboBoxItem` Style

Example:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    .............
    <Border x:Name="ItemBorder" Padding="2,0"  BorderThickness="1"  CornerRadius="3">
        <ContentPresenter /> <!-- no content binding -->
    </Border>
```

Here is a simple example that shows this working

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication13.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" x:Name="UI" Width="343" Height="744.625" >
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                        <Border x:Name="ItemBorder" Padding="2,0"  BorderThickness="1"  CornerRadius="3">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" DisplayMemberPath="State" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            Items.Add(new ComboBoxModel { Name = "Name" + i, State = "State" + i });
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ComboBoxModel> _items = new ObservableCollection<ComboBoxModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<ComboBoxModel> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set { _items = value; }
    }

}

public class ComboBoxModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

Result:

[image] [image]

Comment: Thanks, you have saved me. Big time. I was trying to do exactly that, for a few hours now, but it just did not want to work.Until I compared your solution with mine and found out a little detail that was different: I did not provide the TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" to the ControlTemplate. When I added this, I have suddenly seen the content. After that, I found a tiny remark in the docs: "Also note that the TargetType property is required on a ControlTemplate if the template definition contains a ContentPresenter.". But NOT in the docs of ContentPresenter (although it is in the examples)

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding DisplayMemberPath}"/>
```

Comment: Nope. You can't even compile it that way since DisplayMemberPath is not a property of ComboBoxItem. If you use ComboBox.DisplayMemberPath, nothing is shown in the dropdown box.